# Smart GWT Role Over Controls for a single column

Tags: java, gwt, smartgwt

I'm using a rollOverCanvas on a grid to give controls as on bellow example. But I need the controls available on one particular column.  how can I set the controls for a particular column. Please assist. 
http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_appearance_rollover_controls

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Do you you mean you want the controls to light up only when you hover over a specific column?  It's difficult to tell by the phrasing of your question.

If so, use the column # as a condition to display the hover, e.g.

```
                if(this.getEventColumn() == this.getFieldNum("capital")){

                return rollOverCanvas;

            } else {

                return null;

            }
```